# An error in calculating a logic formula?

Tags: logic

I am reading a textbook on Set Theory (Set Theory, An Intuitive Approach by Lin) and one of the problems asked me to prove this:
$$p\land (p\to q)\land (p\to \lnot q)\equiv c
$$
I solved this question in two ways:

1. I used the associative law to group the first two premises and calcualed them
   $$p\land (p\to q)\equiv q\ (Modus Ponens)
   $$
   Then I calculated the last premise with the result I obtained above
   $$q\land(p\to \lnot q)\equiv q\land (q\to \lnot p)\equiv \lnot p\ (Contrapositive Law, Modus Ponens)
   $$
   and ended up with $\lnot p$ as the final answer.
2. I used the associative law to group the last two premises and calculated them
   $$(p\to q)\land (p\to \lnot q)\equiv p\to (q\land \lnot q)\equiv p\to c
   $$
   Then I calculated the first premise with the result I obtained above
   $$p\land (p\to c)\equiv c
   $$
   and I ended up with $c$ as my final answer, which is what the book wanted.

So my question is, why do I get two answers based on how I group the premises (when Associative Law is known to hold)?

Any advice would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the Modus Ponens correctly. The proposition $p\land(p\to q)$ is not equivalent to $q$, as you can see by considering the case where $p$ is false and $q$ is true.

Comment: I see what I did wrong. Thanks for pointing it out! Modus Ponens was an implication, not a if-then statement. Simple mistake, my bad ='(